# Block internet access from guest network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I have a TPLink Deco X20 wireless router and I would like to set up a guest wifi network where all clients can talk to each other, but not to the Internet.

(Ironically, my search results contain lots of solutions to the opposite problem.)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specific router, but I doubt there's a direct way to do it (because, as you said, the usual requirement is to offer network isolation while keeping an internet connection active).

One way of achieving what you want is by creating an access rule where devices *not* on your approved MAC address list (containing only the devices you want to connect to the internet) is blocked. This means, devices connected to the guest network cannot access the internet, but can still connect to each other (assuming network isolation is off).

Another way would be, if your router supports it, to activate bandwidth control for guests and set it to 0. I'm not sure if it works as intended (never tried it myself; some models might interpret "0" as "no limit"), but it's an idea.

Finally, a more hacky way would be to use a second router. A used model would cost peanuts, it doesn't need to be connected to the internet (which means, you can place it anywhere you'd like), and you would just create a WiFi network where everyone could connect to (and to each other) with no internet access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately network isolation cannot be turned off  and there is no bandwidth limit setting. (I know, TP-link has done a rather bad job with this device. It's not even possible to select wifi channel.) Using a separate router is an option. But I cannot really get full coverage with one access point only. (The X20 is really a mesh with 3 devices.)

Comment: When you say "network isolation cannot be turned off", do you mean there is no such option for your router and it's always on by default? If that's the case, then you need more routers

Comment: I mean that the guest network and the main network are always isolated from each other. Sorry for being unclear. It is the option to change isolation that is missing.